# How to insert html tags using foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

I having some problem on how to put my html tags to my php foreach.

First I have this code and works fine with the layout.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_bname}:</strong><span>'.$row->comminame.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_yrlaunched}:</strong><span>'.$row->mdeveloper.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_yrcompletion}:</strong><span>'.$row->gatedcommunity.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_tfloors}:</strong><span>'.$row->theme.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_bheight}:</strong><span>'.$row->resbuilding.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span> <strong>{lang_developer}:</strong><span>'.$row->commbuilding.'</span>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';




}
```

Now I change my code(check below) and got confused how to put html code like from my previous code.

Here's my code below

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php foreach ($treefields as $key=>$item): ?>
      <?php if($key==0)echo '<div class="additional-amenities">' ?>

      <?php if($item['title'] == $estate_data_option_1057): ?>
      <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><?php _che($item['title']); ?> 

      <?php if (count($item['childs']) > 0):
          end($item['childs']);
          $lastElementKey = key($item['childs']);
          foreach ($item['childs'] as $key_c=>$child): ?>
          <?php if(!empty($child['url'])): ?>
          <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><a href='<?php _che($child['url']); ?>'><?php _che($child['title']); ?></a>
            <?php else:?>
            <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><span><?php _che($child['title']); ?></span>
      <?php endif;
      if($lastElementKey != $key_c)echo ' - ';?>
      <?php endforeach;endif; ?>
           <?php echo '</div>';?>
      <?php else: ?> 
      <?php  ?>   
      <?php endif;?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

Thank you!

**I don't have problem with my values, Just having trouble Inserting html tags**

Comment: You should post a sample value for `$treefields`

Comment: andddd your question is?

Comment: Maybe you should extract a method like your original one that just outputs a string of HTML that you can use in your foreach loop? It would make it a bit less confusing. Mixing PHP tags and with HTML makes things a bit messy 

Comment: Are you using multidimensional arrays? `as $key=>$item`. Is `$item` an array? It doesnt sound logic to me.

Comment: And you miss one endif. Ill show you some sample code in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing HTML and PHP is always a pain. Best is to use PHP only within PHP tags, and HTML outside of these. Like this:

**And** you forgot one `endif;`.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php foreach($treefieldsas as $row):
        if($row['id'] == 0): ?>
            <div class="additional-amenities">'

                <?php if($row['title'] == $estate_data_option_1057): ?>

                    <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><?php _che($row['title']); ?>

                    <?php if(count($row['childs']) > 0):
                        end($row['childs']);
                        $lastElementKey = key($row['childs']);
                        foreach($row['childs'] as $row2):
                            if( !empty($row2['url'])): ?>
                                <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><a
                                        href='<?php _che($row2['url']); ?>'><?php _che($row2['title']); ?></a>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span>
                                <span><?php _che($row2['title']); ?></span>
                            <?php endif;

                            if($lastElementKey != $key_c):?>
                                -
                            <?php endif; 
                         endforeach;
                    endif;
                endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>

        <?php endif;
    endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

If have no clue what you code is doing. So I changed it a bit, feel free to change it back to the values you are using. But something like this should work.

**Harder to read:**

For example this piece of code would be harder to read, since everything is within PHP:

```
<?php if($row['title'] == $estate_data_option_1057):
{
    echo '<span class="available" ><i class="fa fa-check-square" ></i ></span >'. _che($row['title']); 
}?>
```

Because the HTML code is within the PHP tags. I prefer to use `:` in stead op `{}`, because it's easier to read.

**Another fact:**

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;
endif;
endif; ?>
```

Is not clean. You should use this:

```
<?php endif; 
endforeach;
endif;
endif; ?>
```

(Staring and ending PHP tags).

Hope this clears something up.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it something like this:

```
$html = "FIXED_HEAD_ELEMENT";

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

$html .= 'YOUR_HTML';

 if (condition == TRUE){
  $html .= 'THIS';
 } else {
  $html .= 'THAT';
 }

}

$html .= "FIXED_BOTTOM_ELEMENT";

echo $html;
```

I always do it like this. It's very clean and readable.